# Suitescript - Scripted Search Error on FAM Asset record: 'altname' invalid search fliter

Tags: filter, assets, netsuite, suitescript

I am searching for records that have the same Name as the current record to prevent a save for duplicate names. I am getting this error on this search: An nlobjSearchFilter contains invalid search criteria: altname.

Yes, 'altname' is the field name. I have also tried 'altName' in the search for curious sake. Is this an invalid search filter? I need to get this value somehow in a scripted search.

```
var name = nlapiGetFieldValue('altname');
var filters = new Array();
var columns = new Array();

filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('altname', null, 'is', name);
columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');

var results = nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_ncfar_asset', null, filters, columns);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching a custom record, use 'name' instead of 'altname'.

Comment: These fields are different. Why would I search for 'name' when I am trying to match 'altname'? Can you explain further? Thanks! (Also I tried doing this and it doesn't work.) name = nlapiGetFieldValue('altname');
            filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('name', null, 'is', name);

Comment: Found only this documentation: "When you use this sort of custom record type as the basis for a new custom record, the altName field is required on the new custom record form. altName is a string field that simply represents a label you give the custom record, to be used in the list view. Be aware that the altName field maps to the field labeled Name in the user interface (which is different from the way the field names map when auto-generated numbers are not being used). Further, the Web services field called Name maps to the field labeled ID in the user interface."

Comment: I am not really sure on the difference but I have not used the altname field when searching for custom records.